# Shape of the orbit in tethered ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, string

For an ideal "string and ball" tethered device  [Tethered ball - Centripetal force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/420260/)  as the one used in traditional argumentations of centripetal/centrifuge forces, what happens if the speed of the ball is not in equilibrium with the weight? On one side the weight will oscillate, I guess, and then on the other side the orbit of the ball will be not a circular orbit.

Will the orbit still be an ellipse? or a different shape?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/471316/179151

Comment: What do you mean by " _if the speed of the ball is not in equilibrium with the weight_ " ? Clarify. What do you mean by a speed and an weight being in equilibrium ?

Comment: @silverrahul I think they mean $m_1v_1^2/r\neq m_2g$

Comment: Not only will the orbit not be elliptical, it will not even be closed! n other words, the extremes of the orbit will move position. [Bertrand's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) states that the only force laws for which closed orbits are possible are the inverse-square law and Hooke's law. The force in this case is constant so the orbit is not closed.